# How to retrieve data and dropdown list month

Tags: php, mysql, database, display

I'm trying to retrieve data from database. I'm using below code:-

```
<?php
  include('header.php'); //Header which contains html, head, etc 
  include('function/dbconnect.php'); //Database connection
?>

<!-- menu bar here -->

        <form method="post" class="form">

        <?php           
            $month          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
            $m_no           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['m_no']);
            $section        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['section']);
            $reporter       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reporter']);
            $location       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
            $incident_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['incident_date']);
            $incident_time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['incident_time']);
            $description    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['m_description']);
            $priority       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['priority']);
            $received_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['received_date']);
            $received_time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['received_time']);
            $issued_to  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['issued_to']);
            $completed_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['completed_date']);   
            $completed_time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['completed_time']);   
            $incident_reason= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['incident_reason']);  
            $m_status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['m_status']);

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%m/%Y')) AS month
                                  FROM tbl_maintenance_form
                                  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%m/%Y') LIKE '%" . $incident_date . "%' or die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error()) ");

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%m/%Y')) AS month
                                FROM tbl_maintenance_form
                                ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%m')
                                ASC");
        ?>
        <div align="center">
            <select name="date" style="width:10%">
                <option selected disabled>-- Sort By Month --</option>
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['month'] . "'>" . $row['month'] . "</option>";
                    }                               
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="mon" id="mon" />

        </div>
        <br />
                <table class="sortable" id='myTable' cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="width:100%;">
                    <tr bgcolor="#66FF99">
                        <td align="center"><b>No.</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Section</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Report By</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Location</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Incident Date</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Month</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Incident Time</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Description of Fault</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Priority</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Received Date</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Received Time</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Issued To</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Completed Date</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Completed Time</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Reason of Issue</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Status</b></td>
                        <td align="left"><b>Details</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
                    ?>
                    <tr class="c1">
                        <td><?php echo $rows['m_no']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['section']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['reporter']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['location']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['incident_date']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['month']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['incident_time']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['m_description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['priority']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['received_date']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['received_time']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['issued_to'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['completed_date'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['completed_time'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['incident_reason'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['m_status'];?></td>


                        <td align="center"><?php echo "<a href='maintenance_edit_report.php?m_no=".$rows['m_no']."'>"?>
                                           <span title="Click to view details"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i></span>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <?php   
                        } 
                    ?> 
                </table>
            <br />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

At first, it returns no wrong and it displays perfectly as I wanted. Somehow while in the process of building the system, I get Boolean error. That's when I realize that there has been some errors in `$query`. Thus, I've deleted `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(incident_date),'%m-%Y') LIKE '%" . $incident_date . "%' or die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error())` from `$query`. However, the system cannot retrieve month.

What I'm trying to do / my desire output is as below BUT:-

1. I have missing month column - value in column = list of month-year of incident_date.

[image]

2. Suppose there's dropdownlist to display data according to the selected month but there's nothing to select. Value in drop down list = distinct list of month-year of incident_date.

[image]

[image]

How am I going to retrieve and display data and make drop down list that displays month and year..?

Comment: incident_date is in datetime format or string?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes , varchar.

Comment: Try retrieving the date without formatting it in the query and echoing it

Comment: @PhiterFernandes , I've tried this `SELECT *, (DATE(incident_date),'%m/%Y') AS month FROM tbl_maintenance_form` and this `SELECT *, (incident_date,'%m/%Y') AS month FROM tbl_maintenance_form` and several others. It returns empty results, boolean and %m/%Y. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Run this code: `SELECT *, incident_date AS month FROM tbl_maintenance_form` and see if it returns a date.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes , it does returns a date. But, how do I get it to return only month and Year?

Comment: You can fetch the month in sql by using `MONTH(DATE(incident_date))`, check if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99078/discussion-between-ferial-ice-and-phiter-fernandes).

Comment: @PhiterFernandes , no. it doesn't work.